# K8 Pod Lifetime: Is Cleanup Necessary?

Tags: kubernetes

The [Kubernetes Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/%22Kubernetes%20Docs%22) say the following:

> In general, Pods do not disappear until someone destroys them. This
>   might be a human or a controller. The only exception to this rule is
>   that Pods with a phase of Succeeded or Failed for more than some
>   duration (determined by the master) will expire and be automatically
>   destroyed.

What is the default value for this duration and how do I set it? My pods also never enter the Succeeded or Failed phase, rather they enter Completed or Error phase respectively. Is this to be expected; are the docs out of date?

I check the pod phases using `kubectl get pods --show-all`, where information about them seems to persist. Is there any additional cleanup necessary? Running `kubectl get pods` without `--show-all` does not show any pods after they destroyed.

I am creating pods with `kubectl apply -f k8/dummy-pod.yaml` and the following yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dummy.3
  labels:
    vara: a
    role: idk
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - image: gcr.io/gv-test-196801/dummy:v2
    name: dummy-1
```

Comment: How are you creating your pods?

Comment: Right now I am just using `kubectl apply -f k8/dummy-pod.yaml` for testing. I plan to eventually do it programmatically using the kubernetes API. Ill add the yaml to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this documentation is out of date.
Pod garbage collection using TTL [was abandoned](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/12055) in favor of a threshold number of terminated pods. `--terminated-pod-gc-threshold` on the kube controller manager ([docs here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kube-controller-manager/)).

Currently deleting a `DaemonSet, Deployment, ReplicaSet or StatefulSet` will orphan its pods by default.
You can work around this by [enabling cascading deletes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/garbage-collection/#foreground-cascading-deletion)

This behavior will change in 1.10

> Prior to apps/v1 the default garbage collection policy for Pods in a
>   DaemonSet, Deployment, ReplicaSet, or StatefulSet, was to orphan the
>   Pods. That is, if you deleted one of these kinds, the Pods that they
>   owned would not be deleted automatically unless cascading deletion was
>   explicitly specified

see [kubernetes blog](http://blog.kubernetes.io/)

Comment: This information is useful, but I still don't completely understand how to cleanup pods without explicitly calling delete. Is there anything I can add to the yaml file that basically tells kubernetes "hey, cleanup this pod when the process exits". Is it possible to use the `--terminated-pod-gc-threshold` flag on GKE?

Comment: I think your use case would be better suited using a `job`, in this case you manually delete the job and the pods will be removed also. no reason you can't cron this to happen automatically though. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/

Comment: The tutorial that I'm following, https://cloud.google.com/solutions/gaming/running-dedicated-game-servers-in-kubernetes-engine, recommends using pods and states that "At first glance, a single process running in a container with a constrained lifetime and defined success criteria would appear to be a use case for Kubernetes jobs, but in practice it's unnecessary to use jobs. DGS processes don't require the parallel execution functionality of jobs...". Any ideas on how they're dealing with pod cleanup, or maybe i'm overthinking things and it is not necessary?

Comment: A pod maps to a container(s), if you've run a docker container and it has exited that is effectively what your completed pod is, in terms of resource usage this is very minimal. Large numbers of terminated pods will be reaped automatically as stated in my answer. I wouldn't worry about clean up. Pods hanging around means you can inspect their logs etc.